# Disable text output for dynamic plotting in jupyter-lab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have two dynamic plots that get values continuously from a generator. The whole thing looks like this.

```
for data in generator(a,b):
    plt.clf()
    f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 12), dpi=90)
    ax[0].plot(data[0])
    ax[1].plot(data[1])
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(f)
```

The problem is that after the execution in jupyter-lab the final plot and countless `<Figure size 1350x1080 with 0 Axes>` text outputs can be seen. Is there a way to disable this or does anyone know of any other way to create a dynamic plot without text output?

Comment: You can set the matplotlib backend as `nbagg` for interactive plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `plt.clf()` directly, pass `clear=True` and `num=1` to `plt.subplots`, this will suppress the output from all but the last plot while also clearing the plot each iteration:

```py
for ii in range(5):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, num=1, figsize=(15,12), dpi=90, clear=True)
    ax[0].plot(np.ones(10)*ii)
    ax[1].plot(np.ones(10)*ii)
```

[image]

You can also supply a different `num` for each figure, if you need to redraw multiple.